# Strip URL in Python

Tags: python, regex, url, strip

I'm quite new to python. I'm trying to parse a file of URLs to leave only a specific part (bold part) of URL.

Here are some example of URL's i am working with:

```
http://www.mega.pk/**washingmachine**-dawlance/
http://www.mega.pk/**washingmachine**-haier/
http://www.mega.pk/**airconditioners**-acson/
http://www.mega.pk/**airconditioners**-lg/
http://www.mega.pk/**airconditioners**-samsung/
```

I have tried some regular expression but it gets very complicated. What I have in mind is remove this "http://www.mega.pk/" from all urls as it is common and then remove anything that is after "-" including all slashes. But know no way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#module-urllib.parse) (formerly urlparse) module. It's built specifically for this purpose.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-dawlance/"

path = urlparse(url).path  # get the path from the URL ("/washingmachine-dawlnace/")
path = path[:path.index("-")]  # remove everything after the '-' including itself
path = path[1:]  # remove the '/' at the starting of the path (just before 'washing')
```

`path` variable will have the value `washingmachine`

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'^.*\/([^/]*)-.*', r'\1', line)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xQ1eF9/2)

Example:

```
>>> s = '''http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-dawlance/
    http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-haier/'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
    print(re.sub(r'^.*\/([^/]*)-.*', r'\1', line))


washingmachine
washingmachine
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same without using a regular expression. The solution proposed by Avinash is cleaner, but the below approach might be easier to understand, especially if you want to modify it at some point:

```
s = '''http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-dawlance/
http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-haier/'''.splitlines()
for line in s:    
   cleanedUrl = line.replace('http://www.mega.pk/**','').replace('/','')
   urlParameters = cleanedUrl.split('-')
   print urlParameters[-1]
```

Or if you prefer, you can use a compacter version:

```
s = '''http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-dawlance/
http://www.mega.pk/washingmachine-haier/'''.splitlines()
for line in s:    
    print line.replace('http://www.mega.pk/**','').replace('/','').split('-')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r"(?is)^\s*https?\:\/\/[^\/]+\/(.*?)(?:\-|\/).*"
>>> res = re.sub(regex, r"\1", PROVIDE_URL)
```

You will get desire result.

Answer (score 0):

use re.sub in couple with lambda function:

```
re.sub(r'^http://www.mega.pk/(\w+)-.*', lambda x: x.group(), line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using urljoin:

```
import urllib.parse


url = "http://www.mega.pk/**washingmachine**-dawlance/"

website = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, '/')

print(website)
```

Comment: result of your solution is the base url without the path, whoever it was useful for me as I only needed the base url